# Mac App Store: changing minimum system requirements

Tags: macos, cocoa, mac-app-store, minimumosversion, minimum-requirements

When I submitted my app to the Mac App Store, it displays something like this to users:

[image]

and it won't allow anybody with an earlier version to download the app.

I see there's a `LSMinimumSystemVersion` key in my app's `Info.plist` which is set to `${MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET}`.

If I want to let users with an earlier version than 10.7 to use my app, can I then just change the Deployment target? Will my app then run on versions earlier than 10.7 (I will be building the app on 10.7)?

Another question, can I make the change without having to wait for Apple to approve the binary again (I just want to change the minimum Mac OS X required version, not anything in the binary itself)?

Comment: You might want to find a way to test on 10.6 before releasing. Hopefully it should be straightforward, but there are plenty of changes that could cause bugs on an earlier OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided your binary supports it of course you can at least set the minimum system requirement to 10.6.6 (when the MAS came out) - and probably 10.6 if you wish.

There is no explicit rule that I know disallowing, say 10.5, but there is one forbidding "deprecated technologies" and this lists Rosetta which would undoubtedly be interpreted as no PowerPC binaries.

It's a change to your binary, it will have to be approved. Put a note in the comments to reviewers section stating that is all you've changed, can't hurt, may help.

Comment: Thanks, I have just resubmitted the app. I'll try to find a 10.6 system to test it on just in case.

Comment: @houbysoft: Track down a copy of VMWare Fusion 4.1 (not 4.1.1) and make yourself a 10.6 VM...

Comment: exactly what I thought about doing. Thanks :)

Comment: what's the reason for it having to be 4.1 btw?